# How to remove Specific Database Engine

Tags: sql-server-2014, database-engine

I want to completely remove only YE\EZEENEXTGEN Database Engine. Not other server engines.

[image: Fig: Servers]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below link to uninstall the instance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup

Comment: it will remove all my servers? i already check this guide. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to stop all SQL related services, since otherwise the uninstall will fail (as the documentation in this link already states).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling SQL Server from Settings/Apps/Installed Apps (Windows 11) does not delete everything related to the software. It allows you to select the SQL Engine you want to uninstall and delete it.

- This method worked for me.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

[image: Step 7]

[image: Step 8]